# How to this percentage to a whole number with decimal places

Tags: javascript, php, percentage

Hi all I have script code which works perfectly and display a pie chart percentages. The percentage displays 15 decimal places and I want this to make it a whole number. Here's my code. Thanks for the help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Total Number of Patients Per Month'
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %';
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: '#000000',
                        connectorColor: '#000000',
                        formatter: function() {
                            return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %';
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Browser share',
                data: []
            }]
        }

        $.getJSON("data.php", function(json) {
            options.series[0].data = json;
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });



    });   
    </script>
```

The chart displays with 15 decimal places, like 15.123456789123456%.

Comment: I don't see any php in there - you should probably drop that tag. Rather add whatever *Highcharts* is.

Answer (score 0):

```
Math.round(15.123456789123456)
15

Math.floor(15.123456789123456)
15

Math.ceil(15.123456789123456)
16
```

replace 15.123456789123456 with this.percentage

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Math.floor()
```

javascript function. You should update your code when the percentage text is added, so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Total Number of Patients Per Month'
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ Math.floor(this.percentage) +' %';
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: '#000000',
                        connectorColor: '#000000',
                        formatter: function() {
                            return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ Math.floor(this.percentage) +' %';
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Browser share',
                data: []
            }]
        }

        $.getJSON("data.php", function(json) {
            options.series[0].data = json;
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });



    });   
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
parseInt( this.percentage )
```

This will give the whole number portion only and while not relevant to your needs also works for negative numbers.

Comment: parseInt( this.percentage ) - it works but it gives a 101 total percentage

Comment: sorry its not 101 but 93 total percentage.

Comment: That is because you are now trimming all the decimals off. Their total amount in your diagram must be 7%. using Math.Round might get you closer, but there is no simple change that can always give 100%. Example: 50.5 and 49.5: Round/Ceil will give 101%, Floor/parseInt will give 99%. You will either need to create a much more complicated calculation to ensure 100% or add an additional 'variance' section to your pie chart which equals the difference (100-total), in this case 7%.

Comment: thanks wiliam wilson for the explanation. my question now is how will I do that variance coding in my given example above to get the 100 percentage.

Comment: Assuming that data is a numbered list as the examples that HighCharts shows you could avoid adding the parseInt/round/ceil, etc. entirely and replace the line `options.series[0].data = json;` with:
`var total = 0;
for( i = 0; i < json.length; ++i )
{
 json[i] = parseInt( json[i] );
 total += json[i];
}
json[json.length] = 100 - total;`
Which will change all of the values and insert the new 'variation'. If it is a more complex structure the parsing/assignment will need some tweaking. *Sorry the comments don't keep newlines.

Answer (score 0):

As we're inside a JavaScript function, how about `Number.prototype.toFixed()`

```
return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage.toFixed(0) +' %';
```

Read on here: [MDN Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

See example here: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EVPEQQ?editors=101)

Comment: What is your input number in that case?

Answer (score 0):

How about using Math.floor(value)

the Html

```
 <p>
    <input type="text" id="source" value="15.123456789123456789">
    <input type="text" id="target" value="">
</p>
<input type="submit" id="floorIt" value="To Integer">
```

the JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#floorIt").click(function (e) {
        var sourceValue = $("#source").val();
        var targetValue = Math.floor(sourceValue);

        $("#target").val(targetValue);
    });

});
```

take a look at this  [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/umunh7pc/%60)

Answer (score 0):

To round the numbers for example to 2 decimals places you may use following:

`this.percentage = Math.round(this.percentage * 100) / 100;`

Comment: I tried your math.round but still has 2 decimal places. with this '+ Math.round(this.percentage * 100) / 100 +' %';

Comment: So I did it intentionally (2 decimal places). If you like to have only an integer part - here are a plenty of answers to do this.

Comment: Sorry, I just understood what you have in mind as a 'whole number' :)